# Need a code that counts the same digit in a number

Tags: c++

As title says , need a code that counts the same digit in a number..

For example:

If I put 54678, it shows me how many number 5 is used in that integer.

```
12341 -- You used number 1 two times
88888 -- You used number 8 five times
```

Thank you for any help, I'm still learning c++

**EDIT:**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int getNumber ()
{
int x;
cout << "Enter a long number: ";
cin >> x;
return x;
}

int getDigit ()
{
int y;
cout << "Enter a single digit (0-9): ";
cin >> y;
return y;
}

int digitCounter ( int x, int y )
{

if ( x < 10 )
{
if ( x == y )
return 1;
return 0;
}
return digitCounter (x%10, y) + digitCounter (x/10, y);
} 


int main()
{
int number = getNumber();
int digit = getDigit();
int count = digitCounter( number, digit );

cout<< "The digit " << digit << " appeared " << count << " time";

if ( count != 1 )
cout << "s";
cout << "." <<endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should ask for something specific. Eg how can I detect a digit in a number etc

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: Modulos (`%`) is your friend

Comment: What have you tried? Show us some code, some logic, some effort on your part.

Comment: It is not clear from your example whether you need to count the occurence of the first digit of the number or to count all occurences of all digits of the number

Comment: I need code that shows user how many times specific number has repeated in certain number, for example :
Enter 5 digit number 15375 => number 5 is used: 2 ,,,
Enter 5 digit number: 56230 => number 5 is used: 1

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a free code generator.

Comment: As others have mentioned, there is confusion about what exactly you want to count, but [here](http://ideone.com/C6au4J) is a possible solution that gives a count of all digits in a number. You should be able to modify it for your purpose.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that, I know you all didn't understand me , but I came up with answer which is in edited post..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a function like this, where n is the number and d is the digit you want to count:

```
int count_dig(int n, int d) {
    int result = 0;
    while (n > 0) {
        if (n % 10 == d) {
            result++;
        }
        n/=10;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Using this, you could print your formatted result like:

```
printf("%d -- You used digit %d %d times.", n, d, count_dig(n, d));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can enter the number as a string and then parse the string.